# Show that Fisher information matrix is the second order gradient of KL divergence

Tags: probability, information-theory

Given the definition of Fisher information matrix 
$$ I_{\theta} = \mathbb{E}_\theta[\nabla_{\theta}\log p_\theta(x)\nabla_{\theta}\log p_\theta(x)^T] $$

and the definition of KL divergence
$$ D_{KL}(p_{\theta_1}||p_{\theta_2}) = \mathbb{E}_{\theta_1}\bigg[\log\frac{p_{\theta_1}}{p_{\theta_2}}\bigg] $$

I am seeking a proof for the identity
$$ I_{i, j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}D_{KL} $$ i.e. $ I = \nabla^2D_{KL} $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are stating the identity using incorrect notation, which is probably the reason you cannot proceed with the proof. The correct statement of the identity appears in the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Relation_to_relative_entropy) article for the Fisher information matrix, namely,

$$
I_\theta = \nabla_{\theta'}^2D_\text{KL}(\theta \| \theta') \mid_{\theta'=\theta} \text{ (*)},
$$
i.e., the Fisher information matrix equals the Hessian of the function $\theta' \mapsto D_\text{KL}(\theta\|\theta')$, evaluated at $\theta'=\theta$,

where 
$$
D_\text{KL}(\theta\|\theta') \triangleq \int_x p_\theta(x)\log \frac{p_\theta(x)}{p_{\theta'}(x)}dx.
$$

When certain "regularity" conditions hold (related to exchanging the order of differentiation and integration), the Fisher information matrix can be equivalently expressed as (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Matrix_form))
$$
I_\theta = -\int_x p_\theta(x)\left(\nabla_\theta^2 \log p_\theta(x) \right) dx,
$$

which is trivial to see that it is equal to the right-hand side of (*).